# Open Balsamiq in new tab

Tags: feature-request, mockups

When using the Balsamiq tool for sketching an answer, we often need to look at the question to see more details and to  get the mockup right. Since Balsamiq opens in the same tab as the question, it forces us to either navigate back and forth between UX.SE and Balsamiq, or to open UX.SE in a new tab and locate the question again.

I think it would be much more convenient if Balsamiq opened in a new tab, which would close once the tool is closed. Not sure if that last bit is possible.

Comment: Or something that makes the overlay transparent for reading would be good. The SE overlays are usually draggable to solve this problem, but the Balsamiq one is much too big for that to work.

Comment: The main problem with this is that it would keep the (normal post) editor visible, so we'd have to find a different way to prevent you from making other edits while the mockup editor is open. I'll think about it. Of course the workaround is to open the question in two tabs.

Comment: You're right about the workaround, and I'd mentioned it in the question, but usually we realize that we need the original only after we've already opened Balsamiq, not beforehand.